Is it impossible to use "relativePath" for "parametersLink" when deploying linked templates?
I want to deploy some ARM templates on the same time and use "relativePath" in the deployment template(mainTemplate.json).
I am writing deployment template on VScode but it turns the below error where "relativePath" for "parametesLink".
Missing required property "uri"
I did not see any mention of "relativePath" in the Microsoft documentation for parametersLink, but can't I use it?
All templates and parameterFiles are in local directory and I use Windows PowerShell when developing.
Any answer would be helped. Thank you.
mainTemplates.json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "env":{
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "storage",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "linked/storage/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_storage.json"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                  "relativePath": "[concat('linked/storage/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_storage.parameters-', parameters('env'),'.json')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "monitoring",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "linked/monitoring/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_monitoring.json"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                  "relativePath": "[concat('linked/monitoring/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_monitoring.parameters-', parameters('env'), '.json')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2022-09-01",
            "name": "notification",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "linked/notification/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_notification.json"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                  "relativePath": "[concat('linked/notification/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_notification.parameters-', parameters('env'), '.json')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}


In ARM templates, parametersLink requires an absolute URI, as specified in the Azure documentation. Unfortunately, you cannot use a relativePath for parametersLink @CuteeeeRabbit

@VinayB I got it. Thank you for the answer.

You can use bicep template for this scenario, it support referencing a local file template.


It impossible to use "relativePath" for "parametersLink" when deploying linked templates

As per Microsoftdoc the parameter link requires uri to mention the location of the parameter file in this relative path doesn't support.

Whereas TemplateLink as per Microsoftdoc this support uri and absolute path to mention the locatiion of the linked templete.
sample configuration with necessary changes as per the requriement.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
         .
         .
         .
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "relativePath": "linked/storage/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_storage.json"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                    "uri": "[concat('https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/templates/linked/storage/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_storage.parameters-', parameters('env'), '.json')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            .
            .
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "relativePath": "linked/monitoring/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_monitoring.json"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                    "uri": "[concat('https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/templates/linked/monitoring/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_monitoring.parameters-', parameters('env'), '.json')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            .
            .
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "relativePath": "linked/notification/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_notification.json"
                },
                "parametersLink": {
                    "uri": "[concat('https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/templates/linked/notification/linkedtemplate_idbridge_base_notification.parameters-', parameters('env'), '.json')]"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

Try replacing the relativePath in parametersLink with a uri that points to the parameters file.
Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-specs-create-linked?tabs=azure-powershell
